# using Jquery Ui - setting width on a particular multiselect box

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery UI like this:

```
$("#companyType").multiselect({
  multiple: false,
  header: "Type",
  noneSelectedText: "Type",
  selectedList: 1
});
$('.ui-multiselect').css('width', '100px');
```

What I'd like to do is set the .ui-multiselect for only the #companyType div. Something like this:

```
 $('#companyType.ui-multiselect').css('width', '100px');
```

Is there a way to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to set that particular css rule for only elements with class .ui-multiselect contained in the div #companyType I think jquery ui has no influence in it.
Try this:

```
$('#companyType .ui-multiselect').css('width', '100px');
```

This will set width = 100px to all elements contained in #companyType that have a class 'ui-multiselect'

Comment: Actually I realize that I didn't set the parent correctly... thank you this worked.

Answer (score 11):

Try this code with minWidth option. It is the minimum width of the entire widget in pixels. Setting to “auto” will disable, and the default is: 225

```
$("#companyType").multiselect({
  multiple: false,
  header: "Type",
  noneSelectedText: "Type",
  selectedList: 1
  minWidth:100
});
```

Comment: Setting the minWidth property was the perfect solution for me.

Comment: The best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

not sure what version you use, but v1.5 includes a new "classes" parameter that you can set for styling your multiselect element.

Have a look here on how to use it :
http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/
it says

> Additional class(es) to apply to BOTH the button and menu for further
>   customization. Separate multiple classes
>       with a space. You’ll need to scope your CSS to differentiate between the button/menu:

Example

```
$("#companyType").multiselect({
classes : "myClass"
});
```

then in the css file use:

```
/* button */
.ui-multiselect.myClass {}

/* menu */
.ui-multiselect-menu.myClass {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple method for adding width to the multiselect list box is like these 
It is easy than adding another class or inline styling

```
$('#companyType .ui-multiselect').width(200);
```

This will set a with of 200 px to the specified list box

Answer (score 0):

For the reference, if you want to a percentage for the width (e.g 100%) apply it within resize event of the window.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('#companyType .ui-multiselect').css('width', '100%');
});
```

You can also assign it to another element's width dynamically:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('#companyType .ui-multiselect').css('width', $('#anotherElement').css('width'));
});
```